# How is the radius of a subatomic particle defined in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction, electrons

How do we define radius in quantum mechanics. A particle has wave-particle duality, so do we define the radius as Compton wavelength or Bohr radius or some sort of superposition of both? I don't think that either of it works, because of the Heisenberg uncertainity principle, the Bohr radius would vary because the electron shell is probabilistic and requires a wave function. Also we have defined classical electron radius, but as the name says it is classical rather than quantum mechanical.

I was curious about this because  as I was estimating the Kugilblitz Swarzchild Radius that is required to produce a Micro Kugilblitz with LHC at it's maximum energy, I got the result but I was unable to find the particle at the same or below size

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing something important about the wave function, so let me address that first off. Just because the wave function is probabilistic does not mean that it has no stable mathematical attributes that we can use to ascribe comparable meaning between systems. For instance, we can calculate $\langle r \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{r} | \psi \rangle$, the expected value of the distance of an electron in some state $| \psi \rangle$ from the  nucleus. This is a readily comparable measure of radial extent from system to system. Of course, there are many other legitimate ways of describing the quantum mechanical extent of atoms, including the Van Der Waals radius and covalent radius, and more niche ones like the ionic and metallic radius. It all depends on the context of your problem which one (or ones) may be useful. See the linked articles on this page for a quick reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius

Secondly, the Bohr radius is a defined constant $$a_0 = \frac{4\pi \epsilon_0 \hbar ^2}{m_e e^2}$$, and so does not vary from atom to atom! What does stably vary is the effective Bohr radius in a single-electron atom/ion with a varying number of nucleons. The result is essentially $r_{mp}(Z) = \frac{a_0}{Z}$, where $Z$ is the atomic number and the subscript $mp$ denotes that this is the most probable radius, not the only radius. This is calculated by taking the derivative of the ground state wavefuntion and finding its root.

I do not have the knowledge to address your latter point, but the fact that you could not find a candidate particle does not inherently mean you actually made a mistake in the math. There may simply be no known particle to satisfy a theory that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If the particle is an elementary particle, the radius is 0.

If it is a composite particle, the radius can be defined depending on some distribution.
For example, the charge radius of an heavy nucleus is defined as the second moment of its charge distribution:

$$
r^2 = \int d^3\mathbf{r} \rho(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{r}^2,
$$
with $\rho$ the charge distribution of the nucleus. In the case of the proton or for light nuclei, the charge radius can be defined as the slope of the electric form factor:

$$
r^2 = -6\hbar^2 \frac{dG_E}{dQ^2},
$$
with $G_E$ the electric form factor.

You can also define it using weak charge, etc.